# Remove TIMESTAMP precision from NOW() result in PostgreSQL?

Tags: sql, postgresql, datetime, timestamp

Is there any way to remove the precision from the result of the NOW() function in PostgreSQL?

```
"2012-08-21 10:23:34.867502"
```

I'm looking for the format to be:

```
"2012-08-21 10:23:34"
```

I'm attempting to update a column of type "timestamp without time zone" with the following SQL:

```
UPDATE table SET column = now();
```

Thanks!

Comment: Does it make any harm? Database should simply skip milliseconds if column type doesn't support them.

Comment: That's good to know, thank you. I wasn't sure if it would affect anything.

Answer (score 16, accepted):

```
UPDATE tbl SET col = DATE_TRUNC('second', NOW());
```

See the docs for [DATE_TRUNC](http://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/static/functions-datetime.html#FUNCTIONS-DATETIME-TRUNC).

Comment: Thank you, pilcrow. I was combing through the documentation and I could not find it anywhere. I guess I was looking in the wrong place.

Comment: @littleK In new code it may be worth using the SQL-standard time functions `current_timestamp` etc instead of `NOW()` or (worse) `'now'::timestamp`. See http://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/static/functions-datetime.html#FUNCTIONS-DATETIME-CURRENT

Answer (score 24):

Simple answer is to cast it to zero precision.

```
select now()::timestamptz(0);
```

Comment: + this method keeps timezone

Comment: `select now()::timestamp(0);` use this one

Comment: This will *round* the fractional time, not truncate it, as the question requires.

Answer (score 4):

You can change the structure of your table il you move the length of the column to 0 in pgAdmin 3 or if you create a table by using **timestamp(0)** like that :

```
CREATE TABLE public.users
(
    id integer serial,
    username character varying(255) NOT NULL,
    email character varying(255) NOT NULL,
    password character varying(255) NOT NULL,
    created_at timestamp(0) without time zone NOT NULL,
    updated_at timestamp(0) without time zone NOT NULL,

    CONSTRAINT users_pkey PRIMARY KEY (id)
);
```

But if you do that an error will occur if you try to insert a timestamp with millisecond.

Answer (score 1):

Use `date_trunc('second', column)` instead of `column::timestampt(0)` or `column::timestamptz(0)`

Using `column::timestampt(0)` may lead to unexpected rounding up column value.

For example, "2022-06-17 23:59:59.9999" turns to "2022-06-18 00:00:00" the same time `date_trunc('second', column)` returns "2022-06-17 23:59:59".

Answer (score 0):

Depending on your requirements, another option is to adjust the precision of the timestamp column itself - setting its precision to 0. This can be useful when using PostgreSQL with legacy programs that don't handle fractional seconds in timestamps.

Answer (score 0):

```
select now()::timestamp(0);
```

in previous answer select `now()::timestamptz(0);` still keeps the timezone.

Comment: This will *round* the fractional time, not truncate it, as the question requires.